# Read from a file and replace it in another file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file which will read from a file and store the text in a variable. Later this variable has to be replaced in another XML file as explained below

1. Loop thru the Inputfile by reading line by line i.e. one line after the other
2. Each time replace the file name that has been obtained from above step in payload.xml
3. Contine with step 2 until end of file is processed. Example input and output is given below

`REM Example            Input:        D:\Data\somefile.txt
    REM    1st Iteration   Output:       D:\Data\file1.txt
    REM    2nd Iteration   Output:       D:\Data\file2.txt
    REM and so on`

I am trying to do the following but it is not working. Please kindly help.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
Set AllInputFile=D:\AllInputFile\FileList_for_Import.txt
SET INTEXTFILE=C:\myfolder\payload.xml

ECHO "ERRORLEVEL 0-Sucesss else fail " %ERRORLEVEL% " " %AllInputFile%1>>D:\Data\debuginfo.txt2>>D:\Data\debugerr.txt

ECHO "###########Start of MAIN OF LOOP ############"

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%AllInputFile%) do (  
  ECHO "ERRORLEVEL 0-Sucesss else fail " %ERRORLEVEL% " " line=%%a1>>D:\Data\debuginfo.txt2>>D:\Data\debugerr.txt
  set "TARG_FILE=%%a"
  ECHO "ERRORLEVEL 0-Sucesss else fail " %ERRORLEVEL% " " "TARG_FILE "%TARG_FILE%1>>D:\Data\debuginfo.txt2>>D:\Data\debugerr.txt
  REM Get the string and store it in a variable
   for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%G in ('findstr /n "^" C:\myfolder\payload.xml') do if %%G equ 2  set "DbgLine=%%H"
   ECHO "ERRORLEVEL 0-Sucesss else fail " %ERRORLEVEL% " " "DbgLine "%DbgLine%1>>D:\Data\debuginfo.txt2>>D:\Data\debugerr.txt 
   SET PREVFILE_NM=%DbgLine:~27,-13%
   ECHO %PREVFILE_NM%

     call set NewDbgLine=%%DbgLine:!PREVFILE_NM!=!TARG_FILE!%%
        echo !DbgLine!
      ECHO "ERRORLEVEL 0-Sucesss else fail " %ERRORLEVEL% " " "NewDbgLine "!NewDbgLine!1>>D:\Data\debuginfo.txt2>>D:\Data\debugerr.txt 
    echo "#######################"
     set SEARCHTEXT=%DbgLine%
       echo "***************"
       echo %SEARCHTEXT%
       echo "***************"
       set REPLACETEXT=%NewDbgLine%
        set OUTPUTLINE=

         REM Replace the file name

            for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"findstr /n ^^ %INTEXTFILE%"') do (
            SET string=%%A
             for /f "delims=: tokens=1,*" %%a in ("!string!") do set "string=%%b"
               if  "!string!" == "" (
               echo.>>%OUTTEXTFILE%
               ) else (
                      SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!
                      echo %modified%
                      echo !modified! >> %OUTTEXTFILE%
               )
              )

    ECHO "ERRORLEVEL 0-Sucesss else fail " %ERRORLEVEL% " " "End of Main Loop Iteration#######################"1>>D:\Data\debuginfo.txt2>>D:\Data\debugerr.txt  
)
```

Best Regards,
Ind.

Comment: "It's not working" is not helpful.  What do you observe your program doing that is wrong, and what should it be doing instead?

Comment: Thank you for your response.
     `call set NewDbgLine=%%DbgLine:!PREVFILE_NM!=!TARG_FILE!%%`
Variable NewDbgLine is NULL and in the debug messages all the messages are going to the error file.
` ECHO "ERRORLEVEL 0-Sucesss else fail " %ERRORLEVEL% " " "End of Main Loop Iteration#######################"1>>D:\Data\debuginfo.txt2>>D:\Data\debugerr.txt`  

Output file is unchanged. Please kindly let me know what I am doing wrong over here.

Answer (score 0):

When using `enabledelayedexpansion` and changing variables in a loop
you need to use `!variablename!` syntax and not `%variablename%`